# If $b^2$ is an integer and $b$ is real, then is it always of the form $b=c\sqrt d$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b^2\in \mathbb{Z}$, can $b$ be of any other form apart from $b=c\sqrt d$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$?

For example, can $b$ be in the form of some other function such that $b^2$ is integer but $b$ isn't.

Comment: Downvote for "I didn't mean that". Say what you mean, please!

Comment: @ProfessorVector Added.

Comment: "the same" as what? Say what you mean, please, not what you don't mean.

Comment: $b=b$ always holds..

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense.  If $b^2 \in \mathbb Z$, then by definition $b = \pm \sqrt{d}$ where $d = b^2 \in \mathbb Z$.  It makes no difference how you express the value of $b$, it is still of the form $\pm \sqrt{d}$.  I'm not sure that you understand what "of the form" means.

Comment: The anser to this question is actually yes. from the fundamental theorem of primes number

Answer (score 2):

$d=b^2$ and $c=1$ seems to work.

Comment: I didn't mean that actually

Comment: So what did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If $b^2$ has prime factorization $p_1^{i_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{i_n}$, then we can put 
$$c = \prod_{k\,:\,i_k\text{ is even}} p_k^{i_k/2}\quad\text{and}\quad d=\prod_{k\,:\,i_k\text{ is odd}} p_k^{i_k}.$$

Comment: But it's exactly what I didn't ask for. I'm sorry but please read the question once again. I had put that as a comment, which I've now posted in the original question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: There always exists such a form, see Gerhard S.'s answer. If you are looking for the smallest $d$ such that $b=c\sqrt{d}$, this is it. If you can't explain your question, you don't understand it well enough.

Comment: is the question clear now?

Comment: A bit, but keep in mind, that $(\cos(\pi/2) + 0^0 + (1-2+1)^3)^{2017}$ is also a way to write $1$. There are many functions $g:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(c,d) = b$ for some $c$ and $d$.